# capistrano deploy can't install nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, capistrano, nokogiri

My `cap production deploy` is failing on nokogiri installation on an Ubuntu 12.04 box:

```
DEBUG [6f355ce8]    Extracting libxml2-2.8.0.tar.gz into tmp//ports/libxml2/2.8.0... OK
DEBUG [6f355ce8]    Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.8.0... ERROR, review 'tmp//ports/libxml2/2.8.0/configure.log' to see what happened.
DEBUG [6f355ce8]    *** extconf.rb failed ***
DEBUG [6f355ce8]    Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I checked said logs and it mentions not finding a C compiler. I tried to install the dependencies for ubuntu on the nokogiri site and the system says they are already installed.

I also tried `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.1'` on the server and it succeeds with no issues, `gem list` shows it installed on the server.

I found a similar question that suggested adding this line to the production.rb

`set :bundle_env_variables, { 'NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES' => 1 }`

Which changes the error to be a bit more specific:

```
DEBUG [1e93b004]    /usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:430:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
DEBUG [1e93b004]    You have to install development tools first.
```

But trying to install them via:

`sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev`

says everything is already installed --and again, nokogiri installs fine outside of the `deploy` task.

Comment: Is there any chance you are using rvm on the server and have not created the correct gemset? If so, try installing nokogiri manually on that gemset.

Comment: I'm using rbenv, sorry forgot to mention it

Comment: I would suggest you tried `bundle install` manually (as the same user capistrano uses). If that goes well you'll know it is a capistrano configuration problem.

Comment: The bundle install works as root, but not as the deploy user. Maybe because of installing nokogiris' dependencies with sudo?

Comment: You should always try to bundle install as the user. If that fails because of missing libraries, you install them (as root) and then try again bundling (as non root)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing one of the ruby dev dependencies for ubuntu: `http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html`

Also, for some reason this server only gave `root` permissions to access some of the nokogiri dependencies, I had to `chmod` them for my deploy user.

Comment: That is a bad sign, most likely it will disturb you in the future

Comment: Yes, there's been a few weird permissions errors on this server and I'm starting to think about dumping it and going with another provider. Couldn't use one of the usual suspects because client wants it hosted in a specific country